# Unrecognized template declaration error - do not get what am i doing wrong

Tags: c++, templates

The class defines objects that are DIMXDIM dynamic two-dimensional arrays that contain objects of any type.
    Ive added c'tor, d'tor, operator =, operator () that allows me to get the value of (2,5) column/row. 
    and a main that demonstrates the action of T from type float and complex.

I have tried to change the declaration of the c'tor but i think it is not the issue. im really lost

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cassert>
using namespace std;
//#define DIM 3


template<class T, int DIM>
class Array {
    T **p;
public:
    template<class T, int DIM>
    class Array(T** p) {
        p = new T*[DIM];
        assert(p != NULL);
        for (int i = 0; i < DIM; i++)
        {
            p[i] = new T[DIM];
            assert(p[i] != NULL);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < DIM; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < DIM; j++) {
                p[i][j] = 3;
            }
        }

    }
    template<class T, int DIM>
    class ~Array() {
        for (int i = 0; i < DIM; i++) {
            delete[]p[i];
        }
        delete[]p;
    }
    template<class T, int DIM>
    Array& operator=(const Array& other) {

        if (this != other) {
            for (int i = 0; i < DIM; i++) {
                delete[]p[i];
            }
            delete[]p;

            this.p = new T*[DIM];
            assert(p != NULL);
            for (int i = 0; i < DIM; i++)
            {
                p[i] = new T[DIM];
                assert(p[i] != NULL);
            }


            for (int i = 0; i < DIM; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < DIM; j++) {
                    p[i][j] = other.p[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    Array<int, 3> ob[][];
    return 0;
}
```

E0065   expected a ';'  Project C:\Users\Lorine E0070   incomplete type is not allowed  Project 
    E0098   an array may not have elements of this type
    C2988   unrecognizable template declaration/definition
    C2059   syntax error: 'type'
    C2334   unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body  C2332   'class': missing tag name
    C3306   '': unnamed class template is not allowed
    C2988   unrecognizable template declaration/definition
    C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '~'

Comment: `template<class T, int DIM> class Array(T** p) {` - this really should be a constructor. I think, you need to read a good C++ book. Choose from those: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Answer (score 1):

There are a few separate errors, but we'll go through them one by one.

**Problem.** This is the wrong syntax to define a constructor. It *looks* like you're defining both a class and a function at the same time, which the compiler finds very confusing.

```
    template<class T, int DIM>
    class Array(T** p) {
        // stuff...
    }
```

**Correction.** We already have `T` defined as a template parameter, so we don't need to re-define it. It *should* be:

```
    Array(T** p) {
        // stuff...
    }
```

**Problem.** A destructor should never be templated, and you shouldn't put 'class' before it:

```
    template<class T, int DIM>
    class ~Array() {
        for (int i = 0; i < DIM; i++) {
            delete[]p[i];
        }
        delete[]p;
    }
```

**Correction.** Just remove `template<class T, int DIM>` and `class`:

```
    ~Array() {
        for (int i = 0; i < DIM; i++) {
            delete[]p[i];
        }
        delete[]p;
    }
```

**Problem.** Unnecessary template before `=` operator. You only need to template an `=` operator if the input type depends on the template.

```
    template<class T, int DIM>
    Array& operator=(const Array& other) {
        // stuff...
    }
```

**Correction.** We can just remove the `template<class T, int DIM>`, since it's unnecessary.

```
    Array& operator=(const Array& other) {
        // stuff...
    }
```

**Problem.** You're declaring a multidimensional c-style array, without specifying the dimensions (c-style arrays must have all (or all but the first) of their dimensions specified at the point they're declared, when used as a local variable).

```
int main() {
    Array<int, 3> ob[][];
    return 0; 
}
```

**Solution.** Either specify the dimensions of the array, or don't use a c-array. (I don't know which one fits your needs. If you post more information I could update the answer to clarify)

**Problem.** There's no default-constructor

**Solution.** Add a default constructor after `public`:

```
    // stuff...
   public:
    Array() {
        p = new T*[DIM]; 
        // More stuff...
    }
```

**Problem.** You immediately discard your parameter in the `Array(T** p)` constructor:

```
    Array(T** p) {
        p = new T*[DIM]; // WTF?? Whatever parameter was passed gets thrown out the window
        assert(p != NULL);
        // stuff... 
    }
```

**Solution:** Do something with the parameter, instead of just discarding it

Comment: WOW! i have nothing to say but WOW. thnk you so much.

Comment: Sure thing! I looked at your code a bit more, and it looks like you could just remove the (T** p) parameter (in the last problem) to make that one your default constructor! Let me know if you have any more questions :)

Comment: thank you very much. is there any chance i can contact you in private and may ask if i have some questions? :)

Comment: That'd be alright! How would you prefer to contact me?

Comment: Maybe E-mail ??

Comment: My email's Antonio@PerezExcelsior.com - you can contact me there! It's a gmail; it's just got a weird end part